Python is not recognizing packages/modules
I'm new working with python modules and packages and I'm building a neural network from scratch so I'm trying to organize the packeges and modules to make everything clearer. Here's how the packages are organized:
----activations/
    __init__.py
    Activations.py

----losses/
    __init__.py
    Losses.py

----optimizers/
    __init__.py
    Optimizers.py

----scrips/
    proffs.py

When I try to import any of the modules from proofs.py like:
import activations.Activations
it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'activations'".
And activations is not even a module (as long as I understand it is a package with a module named Activatios.py). Can anyone help me to solve this? Thank u!
I already tried running the proofs.py file out from the scrips directory and it seems to recognize the existence of something called "activations" but as a module, again, as I understand it is a package.

make sure you installed the packages in the correct environment. perhaps you forgot to install the packages? anyway create a virtual environment if you don't have one, then in powershell activate the venv and in that venv-activated terminal use pip install [list of packages you need]. after that it should install all of the packages you wanted to that environment and it should recognize them
